# Why default flutter icon app is shown when clicking overview button?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, icons

On my phone "desktop" I can see the custom icon I have set up for my app (by placing the images inside the mipmap folders and referencing them inside AndroidManifest).
However when I click the overview button, I still see the default flutter icon associated with my app.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest flutter_launcher_icons package for changing Flutter application icon.
As you have to define an icon for different resolutions.
But when using flutter_launcher_icons , you just define/update your icon app once.it's easy to use  just follow the guide : 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#book-guide

Comment: I used flutter_launcher_icons but the icon in the Overview is still the default flutter icon

Comment: can you add a screenshot ? and the steps you've done ?

Comment: Actually I retried now and it works. I redid the whole process once again, I guess I mistyped something somewhere, thanks!